Isn't it a little excessive for an RO system to take 24 hours to purge before its water is safe for consumption?
I have the Whirlpool WHAROS5 RO system. Its manual says I must let water drain for 24 hours to purge the system. This sounds a little excessive, and much precious water will be wasted this way. Do you think this is necessary?
The link to the manual is here


What makes you think it isn't necessary? The manufacturer does not earn any extra money by making you follow this procedure, so why would they specify it without a good reason?

will be slow trickle

Save the water and use it for watering plants or other water uses that doesn't involve direct human consumption.

If you properly performed Step F in the manual, there will be 3 ml of poisonous bleach in your new RO storage tank tube.  Properly purging the system after that is necessary to avoid drinking excessively chlorinated water.

According to the water rates in a random city in California
https://www.hayward-ca.gov/water-and-sewer-rates
one gallon of tap water is about 0.01$.
It's not easy to estimate how many gal/24hour the system will need, but the manual says "slow trickle". Assuming it takes 10min to fill a gallon, in 24h you will use 144 gallons that will cost 1.44$, hardly anything comparable to the cost of installation of a system like that. Even if the trickle rate is 10 times as much (one gallon a minute) the expense will still be negligible at around 15 dollars.
